# Scroll continuously rather than in steps

Tags: windows-10, mouse, scrolling, logitech-mouse

I have a Logitech mouse, and when using it in the free scroll wheel mode (rather than with the physical steps), it feels very unnatural; the screen only is scrolled when I have pushed the mouse a certain amount, going in steps.

Is there a way to change this and have the motion of the screen directly correspond to how I am actually manipulating the wheel?

I am on Windows 10, using a G502 Lightspeed.

Comment: No, that is the way the hardware is designed and the OS operates. However, you can make scrolling appear smoother: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-smooth-scrolling/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik OS would handle it, it works for touchpads for example as long as drivers support it. But you're right that mouse wheels are built to detect steps only.

Answer (score 2):

There is a trick actually in addition to what guys commented up there. You can click the mouse ball or middle button which will enable scrolling. Now if you move your mouse a little down, it will start scrolling. Its like an accelerator, so if you move mouse arrow a further down, scrolling will be faster.

Comment: Good suggestion, though it only works in some applications, e.g. most web browsers.